# How to remove header from XML document using org.w3c.dom classes?

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I want to remove

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

tag from the xml. I have used XMLWriter for string representation of class. It is generating the above tag by default. Now I want to remove it.

Is there any standard way of doing it in org.w3c.dom for Blackberry ?

Comment: Could you please tell why do you want to remove that tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```